# Expressing a polar equation in rectangular form and then graphing it

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\theta =-\frac {\pi}{ 2} $$

This question confuses me because the only way to find the Cartesian coordinates for this must be by using tangent. And this is where I get confused:

$$ \tan\theta =\frac { y }{ x } $$

$$\tan(-\frac {\pi}{2 })=\frac { y }{ x } $$

$$\frac { y }{ x } =\frac { -1 }{ 0 } $$ Which is undefined? So where do I go from here? I am so confused by this.

Comment: Why do you need to convert to rectangular form? It should be clear that $\theta = \frac{-\pi}{2}$ forms a line in the plane.

Comment: That is what I am being told to do

Comment: Okay, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just visualize what is going on in $r$-$\theta$ coordinates: $\theta=-\pi/2$ and $r$ is free to vary, so we get the line $x=0$.

On the other hand, $x=r\cos\theta=r\cos(-\pi/2)=0$ and $y=r\sin\theta=r\sin(-\pi/2)=-r\cdot 1=-r$, but $r$ is free to be anything. So you get the set of points in $x$-$y$ coordinates given by $\{(0,y):y\in\mathbb{R}\}$, which is just the line $x=0$.

Comment: So then graphed on a polar graph, it would be along the vertical line $-\frac { \pi  }{ 2 } $ and $r$ could be anything so it is the entire vertical axis?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: I think I made a mistake too. Isn't $r \ge 0$?

Comment: @GabrielH: Not necessarily. Different [sources](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-graph-polar-coordinates-with-negative-value.html) handle it [differently](http://math.etsu.edu/multicalc/prealpha/Chap3/Chap3-2/printversion.pdf).

Comment: Interesting. It does seem weird though, the concept of radius varying over *negative* values.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964980/in-polar-coordinates-can-r-be-negative) too.

Answer (score 2):

In rectangular coordinates we have:
$$x = r \cos \theta = r \cos (-\frac{\pi}{2}) = r \cdot 0 = 0.$$

So, the equation is simply $x=0$ as $y$ will vary based on $r$ which takes on all real values.