# How do I graph (-2,30) on a polar grid?

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I tried to graph the point $(-2,30)$ on a polar graph and I think I got it wrong, how should it be graphed?

[image: This is my answer]

Comment: Which is your answer, i.e. which color dot? The diagram doesn't seem to have radii marked.

Comment: @cosmo5 It is common to see $r<0$ in polar plots; in particular, most (all?) graphing calculators accept $r<0$. If you try $r=-1$ in Desmos, for example, you'll get a circle. The natural convention is  that $(-r,\theta) = (r,\theta+\pi)$.

Comment: @Théophile Ok, I just saw [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/964980/in-polar-coordinates-can-r-be-negative) and it makes sense. Thanks :)

Comment: @cosmo5 Sure thing. Wikipedia has more to say about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Uniqueness_of_polar_coordinates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your diagram is a bit confusing, but your answer may be correct.

If your co-ordinates represent $(r, \theta)$, and if $30$ should be $30^\circ$, and if the red dot is the point in question, and if it is two units away from the origin (there is no indication of units), then you are correct.

This is under the [usual convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Uniqueness_of_polar_coordinates) that $r<0$ is valid and represents a point in the opposite direction from $\theta$ at a distance of $|r|$ from the origin.

The green dot in your diagram beside the label $(-2, 30)$ is in fact $(2, 30^\circ)$. (Again, assuming that it's two units away from the origin.) If the final dot is the red dot, it would be better to place the label beside it.